# cannot install visual studio 2017 on my new dell PC of windows 10 home

Tags: visual-studio

I cannot start the visual studio 2017 community installer program on my new DELL Optiplex 7050 SFF PC, it's running win10 home OS.
It's has no error reported, the installation program simply stop after a flash on the screen.
By the way, it's same failure behavior when I try to install .net framework 4.5.

anyone can help?

Comment: 1. try install as administrator, 2. try on a clean new windows 10 installation (format your). Windows is very unpredictable once you could installed a lot of other software that can avoid the VS installation.

Comment: Windows 10 ships with .NET Framework 4.6.x and 4.7. Thus, what happens to .NET Framework 4.5 installer is perfectly normal. About Visual Studio installation, there should be a log file you should Google how to find and analyze.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I finally find a solution by moving the installation file to a new folder like C;\. This is a totally new DELL desktop and shipped with windows 10 home, there may have some authorization on the folder missing. By the way, the installation also works after I reinstall the OS.